# What does required:true do in a Mongoose Schema? Below is an example

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
 var AnimalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, require: true},
  age: {type: Number},
  bread: {type: String}
});
```

I then created a form in index.html like this,

```
<form ng-submit="createAnimal()">
        <input ng-model="newAnimal.name" type="text" placeholder="...name">
        <input ng-model="newAnimal.bread" type="text" placeholder="...bread">
        <input ng-model="newAnimal.age" type="number" placeholder="...age">
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

Even if I leave the name field blank, rest of the form gets added to the mongo document. I thought if required is set to true in the schema, it would throw an error to the client that the name field could not be added.

I looked on mongoose documentation and there seems to be no explanation. Also could not find anything on the web.

Comment: An empty string is still a string ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it should be

```
required: true
```

instead of

```
require: true
```

that's probably why the parameter was omitted and data has been saved to collection

Comment: It was 'required' in my code. I just misspelled it here on stackoverflow. I meant required.

Answer (score 0):

As @maurycy mentiond it should be

```
required : true
```

this is the Mongoose required validator:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required